# Amazon Web Services Services Increasing - I have terminated all

Tags: amazon-web-services

Can anyone help me, I have tried to use the free tier on AWS and stopped all instances but these 3 services are constantly growing, any idea why?

Under AWS Key Management Service: I have none customer managed key, there is one AWS managed key but it cannot be deleted.

As for Amazon Simple Storage Service there are no buckets.

I have tried and stopped all instances [Free tier usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QlAlz.png)

Comment: Do not worry. Those services are within the Free Tier and you have not been charged anything. If you go to the Billing Console and select **Bills** you will see a breakdown of charges (which should be zero).